# Marking parent item as active when on child page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation bar consisting of LI elements for the parent level. Each section which contains child pages are embedded with another unordered list. When viewing the page of a child element, the child LI gets the class 'active', but the parent does not. How do I assign the active class to the parent item as well with jQuery or CSS?

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML and talk in specific IDs or Classes?

Comment: Including at least some code would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `closest()` it selects the closest parent matching the selector.  So if your child element is several elements deep it will still find the right parent as opposed to `.parent()` which only grabs the immediate parent or `.parents()` which grabs all the parents up until your selector.

```
$('.child').closest('.parent').addClass('active');
```

Comment: That should probably be `$('.child.active')`.

Answer (score 0):

It's still beta, so I don't know if you're using jQuery UI Menu already (or if you're not using any JavaScript at all yet)?  However, with [jQuery UI Menu](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Menu), something like this:

```
function activate_parent(e, u){
    $("#ui-active-menuitem").parents("li").filter(function(i){
        return !($(this).closest("ul").hasClass(".ui-menu-flyout"));
    }).find("a").addClass(".ui-state-hover");
    return;
}

$("#menu").menu({
    'focus': activate_parent
});
```